# select a all div with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I currently have this html:

```
   <div class="col-xs-12 col sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="sounds">
     <span data-sound="capice">capice</span>
    </div>
   </div>
```

and this js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span').on('click', function(){
    var file = $(this).attr('data-sound');
    var audio = new Audio(fileFormat + '/' + file + '.' + fileFormat);
    audio.play();
  });
});
```

I want to change `$('span')` in JS to be able to select the div named "class: sounds"

Comment: Try like this $("div.sounds").on("click",function(){ var spn_file = $(this).find("span");});

Comment: Thanks kamal i try: $("div.sounds").on("click",function(){ var spn_file = $(this).find("span");});
But it didn't work.

I'm sorry Barmar i just start coding and i learn with online resources so sometimes i struggle on simple things.

Comment: If that is the only `sounds` class on the page you can just do `$(".sounds:first")` as your selector and it should work. That will select the parent div you just need to get to the span inside of it which is where Kamal's `var spn_file = $(this).find("span");` comes in then to complete your js you would just replace `$(this).attr('data-sound');` to `spn_file.attr('data-sound');`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the actual selector? Like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.sounds').on('click', function(){
    var file = $(this).attr('data-sound');
    var audio = new Audio(fileFormat + '/' + file + '.' + fileFormat);
    audio.play();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx Ibanez i had try it but i wasn't working cause i forget to also change html for this js code to work:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="sounds" data-sound="capice">
        <span>capice</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

so this html + this js works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.sounds').on('click', function(){
    var file = $(this).attr('data-sound');
    var audio = new Audio(fileFormat + '/' + file + '.' + fileFormat);
    audio.play();
  });
});
```

thanks a lot every one !

Comment: Glad to have helped, if my answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.